# Importing XML data into MS SQL server programmatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have **[5 large XML files](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)** which I am keen to analyse. All of them are **too large to open in a text editor** and so I do not know their XML schemas.

I have tried to import them into SQL server, however the process has given me an error even though I am pretty sure they are valid, as they were sourced from very **reputable programmers**.

I have also tried other methods but each struggles with the large file sizes (*MySQL*) or state that the files contain invalid XML characters (*Access & Excel*).

How can I **read and insert the data programmatically?** Can this be done via SQL query?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you tpye the file at console and look at its schema? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#type

Comment: giant xml files with no documented schemas != reputable programmers

Comment: I have now put a view of the file schema on my blog. logicflip.com/2009/06/stackoverflow-download-data-schema Hope it helps! http://www.jonwinstanley.com/2009/06/stackoverflow-download-data-schema/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this blog post by unofficial StackOverflow team member Brent Ozar:
http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/how-to-import-the-stackoverflow-xml-into-sql-server/

Comment: "UPDATE 2013: This code is no longer available. The size of the StackOverflow export has grown beyond what you can import with this method". Worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

***As of 2013...***

The only time saving option in my opinion to load large/huge XML files in SQL Server is (as someone previously briefly mentioned) to use the **SQLXML 4.0** library.

This is the solution I adopted to load huge XML files (**7GB in size**) on a daily basis. The previous process which was using C# manipulation in the Script Task took hours to complete. Using SQLXML 4.0 takes **15-20 minutes**. How to install SQLXML 4.0. step by step  [here](http://dwbiexpert.com/sqlxmlbulkload-ssis-task). For practical examples in how to do it end to end [follow this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171806.aspx).

My XML has also nested elements, so it's quite complex, the result is 10 tables with 2.5 to 4 million rows each (the daily file sometimes is more than 7GB). My work was based purely on information I learned and applied from the two links provided above.

- **Advantages**:

  - it's fast
  - it's Microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30403)
  - SSIS package will be very much simplified
  - you don't need to spend hours and hours to change the SSIS package if your XML schema changes. SQLXML is able to create the tables in the SQL Server for you every time you run the package, based on the XSD relationships you provide.
- **Disadvantages**

  - creating the XSD may take a while and requires some knowledge. When I did it I learned something new, so this was not a real a disadvantage for me.
  - when seeing how simple the SSIS package is, your manager will have the impression that you didn't do any work.

To view large files use [Large Text File Viewer](http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html), nice little gem.

***Note: The question is quite old, but the "issue" remains hot. I added this post for the developers who Google how to BULK LOAD XML files in SSIS and land here.***

Answer (score 4):

Try the free LogParser utility from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

It's designed to give you SQL-like access to large text files including XML. Something like

```
Select top 1000 * from myFile.xml
```

...should work to get you started. Also, beware that the documentation will appear in your start menu along side the executable after installation--I don't think there's a good copy on line.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of have to know the schema.  Try downloading [TextPad](http://textpad.com/) or something similar to view the files.

Once you know the schema you can do a couple of things to get them into SQL.  One approach would be to use OpenXML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx.

Comment: I am using Notepad++ already. That is usually pretty solid. However these files vary between 19mb and 850mb. Unfortunately, the one I really want to see is the big one.

Comment: The only editor I know of that can handle files larger than your RAM size is UltraEdit (http://www.ultraedit.com/)

Comment: I have plenty of RAM, 1.5gb (1.05 available). But will take a look at UltraEdit anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the mssql xml parser extensively, the bcp.exe utility works great for this. The trick is coming up with the right row terminator since it has to be a value that cannot occur in your document. For instance you can do this:

```
create table t1(x xml)
```

Ceate a simple text file that contains *only* your chosen delimiter. For example place this string in delim.txt:

> -++++++++-

Then concatenate that to the end of your document instance, from the command line:

> copy myFile.xml + delim.txt out.xml /b

After this you can BCP it into the database like :

> bcp.exe test.dbo.t1 in out.xml -T -c
>   -r -++++++++-

If the document is UTF-16 then replace the -c switch with -w

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  [SQL Server XML Bulk Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171769.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did was to get the first X bytes (e.g. the first 1 MB) of the XML files so I could take a look at them with the editor of my choice.

If you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed you already own a nice GNU utility to achive this: **head**

```
head.exe -c1M comments.xml > comments_small.xml
```

Alternatively you can find a native port of the most GNU utilities here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Good plan. Although some uncommon tags might be missed off in the first few records.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing very large files, I've found the [V file viewer](http://www.fileviewer.com/index.html) to be excellent.

I've used it on files as large as 8GB.  For files which are fixed record length, it is extremely easy to navigate based on block size, because it is disk-based.

Note that there is no editing capability.

Having said that, one difficulty with XML is that it's not really a good format for large "streams", since it has an overall beginning and end structure, and a parser which cannot hold the entire file in memory may have to do some pretty fancy tricks to ensure that it complies with a DTD or schema.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this bog post http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/01/15/parsing-xml-into-a-table-structure-possible-update/

And this so question: [Parsing XML into a SQL table WITHOUT predefining structure. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444678/parsing-xml-into-a-sql-table-without-predefining-structure-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `OPENROWSET` to import your big XML files into a SQL Server table?

```
CREATE TABLE XmlTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    XmlData XML
)

INSERT XmlTable(XmlData)
  SELECT * FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK '(your path)\xmldata.xml',
    SINGLE_BLOB
) AS X
```

Since I don't have any 5GB files at hand, I can't really test it myself.

There's another way you might tackle this : streaming Linq-To-Xml. Check out this [blog post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2007/12/11/linq-to-xml-over-large-documents.aspx) where James Newton-King shows how to read XElement one-by-one, and a two-part series [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/05/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-1.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx) on the same topic by the Microsoft XML team blog.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You should load your XML into an [XML database](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/ProdsNative.htm), e.g. [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html) or [Xindice](http://xml.apache.org/xindice/)

Also, I'm not sure if it can scale to 850mb, but [First Object XML Editor](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm), and the parser library on which it's built, can handle quite large files.

Also, [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) should display your files without breaking a sweat.